# How to unable button if textbox suddenly have values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can anyone help me how to make my button disable if my `texbox` suddenly filled with text without clicking the textbox to input something.

My problem is my code wont work. Does anyone know how to do it.

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" class="number" />
<input type="text" name="name2" id="name2" class="number" />
<input type="submit" name="send" id="send" class="hey" value="one" disabled />
</form>
```

script code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.number').blur(function () {
        if ($.trim(this.value) == "") {
          $('#send').attr("disabled", true);
        }
      else {
            $('#send').removeAttr("disabled");
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use combination of input, blur and keyup events to be safe:

```
$('.number').on('keyup blur input', function () {
    $('#send').prop("disabled", !$.trim(this.value));
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pb9vw/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.number').keyup(function () {
    if ($.trim(this.value) == "") {
      $('#send').addAttr('disabled');
    }
  else {
        $('#send').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `keyup` instead of `blur` and `prop()` instead of `attr()` The blur is triggered when input gets or loose focus. The prop should be use for boolean attributes like checked disabled etc.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5MN3U/)**

```
$('.number').keyup(function () {
    if ($.trim(this.value) == "") {
      $('#send').prop("disabled", true);
    }
  else {
        $('#send').prop("disabled", false);
  }
});
```

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes
>   that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as
>   the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the
>   .prop() method, [reference](https://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure the button is only enable when the two textbox are filled, then you can do:

```
function doCheck() {
    var allFilled = true;
    $('input[type=text]').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            allFilled = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
    $('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', !allFilled);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type=text]').keyup(doCheck);
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pb9vw/1/)**