# Remove disable button if the textbox have values inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

can anyone help me how to remove button disable attribute if the the textboxes with class(`number`) have values inside and disable again if the textbox is empty.

current code:

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="number" value="hello" readonly />
<input type="submit" name="send" id="send" disabled />
```

script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.number').on('input', function () {
    $('#send').prop("disabled", !$.trim(this.value));
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your current code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/b2Yct/

Comment: You could just ask in the original question http://stackoverflow.com/q/21981163/949476

Comment: Right now your input is `readOnly`, is it gonna be always like that?

Comment: seriously none of you gets my problem =.=

Comment: i want to unable the button if the textbox has values inside look at the input attribute

Comment: @Alvaro yes...because i have a search texbox and if i type a name it will show in the textboxes with class(number) and if i type wrong in the search textbox it will automatically empty the textboxes with class(number)

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
 $('.number').keyup(function() {
    if($(this).val() != '') {
       $('#send').removeAttr('disabled');
    }else{
       $('#send').attr('disabled',true);
  }});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current code works fine: [**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/b2Yct/1/).

The problem is that your `.number` element is set to `readonly`, meaning it doesn't accept any `input` (which is the event you're handling).

If you're setting the `readonly` property on the server side, I imagine you can also set the `disabled` property on the server side as well.

Comment: i purposely put the readonly and i put values inside the textbox

Comment: i want is if i run the run it will automatically remove the disable attribute in the button

Comment: @user3340637 simply add in `$('#send').prop("disabled", !$.trim($('.number').val()));` outside of the `input` event: http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/b2Yct/2/

Comment: u get my point now what if the textbox has empty values and its readonly..i want is it will disable again automatically...because i have a search textbox that when i search the inputs will show in the other textboxes with class(numbers) and when i search wrong it will empty the textboxes with class(number) and the button will automatically disable.

Answer (score 0):

You could listen for `keydown` events and every time a key is pressed, you check the value of the element:

```
$( ".number" ).on( "keydown", function ( e ) {
    var current_value = $( this ).val();
    // The keypress event actually happens before the character is inserted. 
    var value = $.trim( current_value + e.which );
    if ( value.length > 0 ){
      $( "#send" ).attr( "disabled", false );
    }
});
```

The only problem with this approach is that it will not work if the user copy-pastes a value into the textbox. The alternative would be to use a `setInterval` to check the input every X seconds.

Comment: Your answer + an onChange/onBlur should covered all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
    /* The keyup event fires right after the user releases a key */
    $(".search-bar").on("keyup", function() {
        var state = this.value === "";
        $("#send").attr("disabled", state);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$('.number').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this.val() == '') {
        $('#send').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#send').attr('disabled', '');
    }
});
```